# ultimo registro entity C# windows form

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, windows, entity-framework

Hola espero puedan ayudarme estoy intentando obtener cuantos registros tiene mi tabla de sql tengo lo siguiente

```
public int  ultimoRegistro()
    {
        var LastRecord = (from c in db.Alumnos
                          orderby c.IDAlumno descending
                          select c).First();
        return LastRecord;
    }
```

pero me da error en los tipos de datos

Comment: Por favor **[edit] la pregunta** con la descripción completa de los errores que tenga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, quieres obtener el último `IDAlumno` almacenado en la tabla `Alumnos`.

El problema con tu código es que está devolviendo toda la entidad `Alumno`, por lo que le faltaría definir cuál es la propiedad a retornar.

Por ello, devuelvo `select c.IDAlumno`.

Para esto, realiza el siguiente código:

```
public int ultimoRegistro()
{
    var LastRecord = (from c in db.Alumnos
                      orderby c.IDAlumno descending
                      select c.IDAlumno).First();
    return LastRecord;
}
```

Comment: Justamente tenía eso en mente, pero soy bastante novato y por ello no terminaba de encontrar la forma. Me sirvió mucho, lea agradezco a todos sus rrspuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas EntityFramework, puedes usar este:

```
db.Alumnos.Max();
```

asi obtendras el ultimo registor por el Id.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la cantidad de registros en tu tabla, tienes que usar el método `Count` de la siguiente forma:

```
public int  ultimoRegistro()
{
    var LastRecord = (from c in db.Alumnos
                      select c).Count();

    return LastRecord;
}
```